# Validation rules for payment cards in a data set

Tags: php, validation

I have the following part of code. I dislike this, because if I need to add additional validation rule, I have to make changes in loop and create a varaible to store boolean result. For example check age.

```
$nums = [];
$linesState = [];
$wrongCardNums = [];

foreach ($lines as $index => $columns) {

    $expired = false;
    $duplicated = false;
    $wrongnum = false;
    $wrongmmyy = false;

    if (isset($columns["NUM"])) {
        $nums[$columns["NUM"]] = $columns["NUM"];
        $duplicated = isDuplicate($columns["NUM"], $invalidCardsDb, $nums);

        if ($duplicated)
            $wrongCardNums[$columns["NUM"]] = $columns["NUM"];
    } else {
        $wrongnum = true;
    }

    if (isset($columns["MMYY"])) {
        $expired = isExpired($columns["MMYY"]);

        if ($expired)
            $wrongCardNums[$columns["NUM"]] = $columns["NUM"];
    } else {
        $wrongmmyy = true;
    }

    $invalid = $expired || $duplicated || $wrongnum || $wrongmmyy;

    $linesState[$index] = array("valid" => !$invalid, "line_index" => $index, "session_id" => $sessionid);
}
```

It is possible to do that more elegant and independent?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226).

Comment: @TobySpeight this has a valid answer now, do you still want t close it?

Comment: @pacmaninbw, the title is somewhat better, but the description of the purpose should still be improved.

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid single-use variables. (`$duplicated`)
2. Use camelcase for variable names for best, shorted presentation in IDEs.
3. Fail early -- this will make truthy outcomes predictably at the bottom of evaluation blocks.
4. Avoid arrowhead / nested condition blocks by using `continue`.
5. Is `isDuplicate()` actually needed? Can it not be replaced with a mere `isset()`?
6. Declare the long line of `$linesState` once, then only update `valid` if/when required.

Suggested rewrite:

```
foreach ($lines as $index => $row) {
    $linesState[$index] = [
        "valid" => false,
        "line_index" => $index,
        "session_id" => $sessionId
    ];
    if (!isset($row["NUM"])) {
        continue;
    }
    $allCardNums[$row["NUM"]] = $row["NUM"];  // store for dupe checking
    if (!isset($row["MMYY"])) {
        continue;
    }
    if (
        isInvalidDbCard($row["NUM"], $invalidCardsDb)  // is blacklisted?
        || isset($allCardNums[$row["NUM"]])            // is duplicate?
        || isExpired($row["MMYY"])                     // is expired?
    ) {
        $invalidCardNums[$row["NUM"]] = $row["NUM"];  // store bad NUMs
        continue;
    }
    $linesState[$index]["valid"] = true;
}
```